# Why does my javascript WebSocket just die? python server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

trying to make a simple text chat socket server. I am very new to coding servers. I have this working code but the problem is that the WebSocket() dies silently on me:

the output in the javascript console is
open
closed

There is very little resources to help me understand this behaviour. Why does my python server kill the connection once the header is sent? Am i sending the response in the correct way? Any help at all would be amazing.

---

Python code:

```
    import socketserver
    import re
    from base64 import b64encode
    from hashlib import sha1

    inited = 0

    class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

        def handle(self):
            global inited
            if(inited==0):
                print(self)
                text = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
                self.upgradeConnection(text)
                self.request.send("a sweet message from the server!".encode("utf-8"));
                inited = 1
            else:
                self.request.sendall("second response!".encode("utf-8"));

        def upgradeConnection(self,text):
            #print("Client wants to upgrade:")
            #print(text);
            websocket_answer = (
                'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
                'Upgrade: websocket',
                'Connection: Upgrade',
                'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n',
            )

            GUID = '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'
            #print(re.search(b'Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', text))
            key = (re.search(b'Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', text)
                .groups()[0]
                .strip())

            #print(key.decode("utf-8"))
            #print(key.decode("utf-8") + GUID)
            #print(sha1((key.decode("utf-8") + GUID).encode("utf-8")))

            response_key = b64encode(sha1((key.decode("utf-8") + GUID).encode("utf-8")).digest()).decode("utf-8")
            #print(response_key)
            response = '\r\n'.join(websocket_answer).format(key=response_key)
            self.request.send(response.encode("utf-8"));




    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Webpage code:

```
    url = "ws://127.0.0.1:9999/";

    var sk = new WebSocket(url);


    sk.onopen = function(e){
        console.log("open");
        sk.send("the client is here!!");
    }
    sk.onmessage = function(e){
        console.log("message");
        console.log(e.data);
    }
    sk.onerror = function(e){
        console.log("error");
    }
    sk.onclose = function(e){
        console.log("closed");
    }
```

Comment: Your server will close the new connection when your `handle` method completes.  You need to remain in this method until either the client closes the connection or the server wants to close it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I since gave up with low level code and used the existing websocket module to good effect :)